# __availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes is empty on iPhone 7+ and iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, rawimage

I'm trying to capture RAW files with AVFoundation. However I'm getting empty array in `__availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`

Here is my snippet

```
if self._photoOutput == nil {
    self._photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    print(self._photoOutput!.__availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes)
}
```

And the output is empty array `[]`

What may cause this?

Answer (score 9):

Here are three things that will cause the `availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes` array to be empty:

1. You are reading the `availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes` property before adding your `_photoOutput` to an `AVCaptureSession` with a video source.
2. You are using the dual camera input. If so, you can't capture RAW images.
3. You are using the front camera. If so, you can't capture RAW images.

Here is some modified sample code from an excellent Apple guide (see link below). I have copied from several places and updated it slightly for brevity, simplicity and better overview:

```
let session = AVCaptureSession()
let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

private func configureSession() {
    // Get camera device.
    guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
        print("Unable to get camera device.")
        return
    }
    // Create a capture input.
    guard let videoInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice) else {
        print("Unable to obtain video input for default camera.")
        return
    }

    // Make sure inputs and output can be added to session.
    guard session.canAddInput(videoInput) else { return }
    guard session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) else { return }

    // Configure the session.
    session.beginConfiguration()
    session.sessionPreset = .photo
    session.addInput(videoInput)
    // availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes is empty.
    session.addOutput(photoOutput)
    // availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes should not be empty.
    session.commitConfiguration()
}

private func capturePhoto() {
    // Photo settings for RAW capture.
    let rawFormatType = kCVPixelFormatType_14Bayer_RGGB
    // At this point the array should not be empty (session has been configured).
    guard photoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.contains(NSNumber(value: rawFormatType).uint32Value) else {
        print("No available RAW pixel formats")
        return
    }

    let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: rawFormatType)
    photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
}

// MARK: - AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate methods

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
                 didFinishProcessingRawPhoto rawSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,
                 resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
                 bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?,
                 error: Error?) {
    guard error == nil, let rawSampleBuffer = rawSampleBuffer else {
        print("Error capturing RAW photo:\(error)")
        return
    }
    // Do something with the rawSampleBuffer.
}
```

***Apple's Photo Capture Guide:***
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/PhotoCaptureGuide/index.html

***The `availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes` property:***
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1778628-availablerawphotopixelformattype)

***iPhone camera capabilities:***
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Cameras/Cameras.html

Comment: It would be helpful to also provide some code that could help fix the issue in addition to explaining what the issue is.

Comment: I realized that it is likely related to the fact that I tried using front camera.

Comment: I see, makes sense. I will update the answer to help future readers.

Comment: I tried to set capture device format with a dimension other than the max. availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes will also be empty. iOS 13.3

Comment: Still not working here :/, it could be becauseI am using an iPad?

Answer (score 2):

One supplyment to @Thomas's answer:

If you change `AVCaptureDevice.activeFormat`, `AVCaptureSession.sessionPreset` will be set to `inputPriority` automatically. In such situation, `availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes` will be empty too.

Comment: yes, this answer is right. my solution is to set `session.sessionPresset` to `.photo` again, will work

Comment: This is a big hole in apples documentation. I could not understand why the availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes kept showing as having no records. Thank you.